# Improve performance with too many directories

Tags: java, linux, file, window, filesystems

In my project every, user can upload some files (about 10 files) on the server.

I decided to create a directory with the name of every user and upload their files inside their corresponding directory.

The users can access their folders directly in `url => {url}/users/userId/file1.jpg`

Because the number of users will increase(1M) there will be many folders. What can I do to improve performance?

Comment: Use the first letter(s) of the username to create subdirectories like /users/u/s/userId to reduce the number of files in each directory - that will improve file access performance (on a typical Unix / Linux box at least, less so if the file system keeps directories in sorted order.)

Comment: You could take the first letter, or the two first letters, of the username, and use it as a sub-directory. But considering that it's about LInux, I doubt you will notice much of a speed decrease even with thousands of directories.

Comment: For better distribution over the subdirectory buckets you can hash the file name first and take a number of hex digits from the hash for the sub directory name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely do some tests with representative amounts of users. If you're starting out with 1 million users, than you should do a performance tests with 1 million accounts and see how it holds up.

You didn't specify which OS and/or filesystem you're using. Assuming it's Linux, you shouldn't really have performance issues: ext3, ext4 and other modern file systems have indexed directories that make it very fast to access individual subdirectories/files within a directory.

You may still be able to boost performance a bit by managing the size of directories, but it won't be orders of magnitude.

However there are other limits: on ext3, you can have at most 32000 subdirectories in a directory, and in ext4 it's limited to a maximum of 64000. So you couldn't have 1 million accounts all under `/users` even if that didn't cause any performance issues.

You can take the first one or two letters of the account name to create subdirectories:

```
String directory = "/users/" + username.charAt(0)+ "/" + username.charAt(1) + "/" + username;
// assuming that usernames need to be at least 2 letters, otherwise extra guards are needed
```

But that will give you a higher concentration in directories with letters that occur more often, such as the "e". Using a hashing function on the whole username gives a better distribution.

You can also record the home directory for a user in a database, giving you more freedom to decide. If you want no more than 1000 files per directory, you can create 1000 numbered subdirectories and assign each newly created account round-robin to one of these buckets.

Note: although Mumrah's concern can be relevant on older OS'es, on Linux with a Logical Volume Manager, you don't need to worry about physical disk sizes as you can easily stretch your filesystem across as many disks as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Some math: 1M users * 10 files * of 1M +-= 10To

If i was you i would create a servlet/REST endpoint mapped on {url}/users

Then in my code i would have a map

`Map<String, String> firstLetterToDisk` which map the first letter of userId to a path

Ex:

```
"a" -> "/disk1/users
"b" -> "/disk1/users
....
"y" -> "/diskN/users
"z" -> "/diskN/users
```

In my code, i would construct the real path of the file and stream the content of the file as response

With this kind of setup you could balance the data and the load on multiple disk

EDIT:

Mapping the first letter to a disk is not the main point here.

The main point is to deccorelate the url from the filesystem using a rule.